# liveSassCompile.settings.savePath when set to null generate css in various folder that contains css why? how to stop from doing that

Tags: wordpress, live-sass-compiler

I want to only watch the scss on the folder I am current on, because not all projects I work the scss on the same folder so I can't specify savePath to a particular path.

I am trying to use liveSassCompile extension on Visual studio code, with wordpress which contains css in various place, when I set the path of the liveSassCompile.settings.savePath to "/" it generates to css in the root of the project, so I have to delete all the extra css then I change the liveSassCompile.settings.savePath to null first time saving only creates on the exact folder I want but when switch projects it generates multiples css again.

Answer (score 0):

If you have the same settings for every project you will **EVER** use then you can change your user settings.

[image: Press F1 and type in user settings. This menu will pop up]

If you choose the UI you can select to change the default below

[image: UI of extension settings]

---

Like every extension, it has default settings. If you don't change them in the project/user settings then this is what the extension will conform to (in this case, saving to the same place as the original file - *[if you're using my version](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=glenn2223.live-sass)*).

**Default**

```
{
    "liveSassCompile.settings.formats": [
        {
            "format": "expanded",
            "extensionName": ".css",
            "savePath": null,
            "savePathReplacementPairs": null
        }
    ],
    // Other settings ...
}
```